# SearchView.setQuery() before user clicked on magnifier menuitem

Tags: java, android, searchview, android-menu

I have a SearchView item in my menu:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/search_toolbar_main"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
    android:title="Search" />
```

Now I want to programmatically open the searchview and set text with searchView.setQuery(). But if I do searchView.setQuery() before user clicked the magnifier menuitem nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call to expandActionView() method to focus it

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu )
{
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu( menu );

    MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem( R.id.search_toolbar_main ); 
    searchMenuItem.expandActionView(); // Expand the search menu item in order to show by default the query

    return true;
}
```